# select elements from matrix based on multiple range values

Tags: matlab

```
a = 1:20;
b = [2,5;12,16];
```

I'm looking for a way to extract the elements in `a` within the range of `b` rows. I tried

```
bsxfun(@(col1,col2) a(col1:col2), b(:,1), b(:,2))
```

but this ignores all but the first row of `b`.

This is the output I expect

```
2 3 4 5 12 13 14 15 16
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `bsxfun` function uses the values defined within each respective row of `a` to create two distinct vectors and concatenate them.

```
a = 1:20;
b = [2,5;12,16];

Range_1 = b(1,:); 
Range_2 = b(2,:);

bsxfun(@(Row_1,Row_2) [a(Row_1(1):Row_1(2)) a(Row_2(1):Row_2(2))], Range_1, Range_2)
```